# Jquery fade blinks/flickers in FireFox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have a simple image slider which worked fine, but not suddenly in Firefox the `fadeIn/fadeOut` blinks once before going to the next `fadeOut/fadeIn`. This is of course very annoying.

I am using FF 27.0.1 on Windows & and 27.0 on Ubuntu. Both show the same effect.

I have tried `fadeOut/fadeIn` and `fadeToggle`, all have the same effect.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h6u72/

```
<style>
#slideshow {
    margin: 10px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 225px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #406dac;
}

#slideshow div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 5px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#slideshow div:gt(0)").hide();

    setInterval(function() {
        $('#slideshow >  div:first').fadeToggle(2000).next().fadeToggle(2000).end().appendTo('#slideshow');
    }, 3000);

}); 
</script>
<div id="slideshow">
<div>
    <img src="images/promo/couple3a_225x225.png" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="images/promo/logo_icon1.png" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="images/promo/logo_icon2.png" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="images/promo/logo_icon1.png" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="images/promo/logo_icon3.png" alt="" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried but cannot reproduce http://jsbin.com/def/1/edit Win/FF27.0.1

Comment: Same as @RokoC.Buljan, Win/Nightly 30.1.

Comment: this is the live situation http://www.secretsensation.nl/home.php . it blinks every transition.

Comment: @CoenDamen, can't see blinking in live version, too? (win7, firefox 27)

Comment: huh ? that is strange, I tested here on Linux and Windows and both have the same effect.